# Different kinds of systems

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

I got interested in learning more about Logic, recently.The first thing i noticed is that this topic is a lot bigger than i expected. As i'm trying to make a sense of it all ( seeing the big picture ) before delving into it, i'm having a lot of questions and i thought of asking help to people that are already acquainted with it.

I'm easily grasping some concepts ( like formal language, language grammar, rules of inference, axioms, theorems ) and they seem to have a common definition over many authors.
Other terms are giving me a really hard time.My question is :

Does the following terms have agreed definitions among logicians ?

Formal System, Logical/Logic System, Proof Systems, Axiom System,Natural Deduction System

If not all of them are universally defined, is there some of them that are pretty much agreed ?

If it latter answer is positive, I would like to know where ( books/sites/resources) i could find information regarding the definition of those terms that are almost completely agreed.   ( Wikipedia doesn't seem to cover it all ).

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I am of the opinion that most of the other terms you list do not have good definitions, nor are definitions needed.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is it for the same reason there's no "definition" of, say, geometry?

Comment: Somewhat, though the terms are at least less broad-reaching. Technical definitions would either leave out some things, or be so broad as to be useless. At any time, one is working with a concrete (at least it feels concrete) class of structures. There, precise definitions are necessary, and possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter three you give are certainly common enough, I would think, that you could use them and logicians would know what you meant. These three terms all belong to a field called *proof theory*, and there are several introductory texts (see third paragraph). However, "formal system" and "logical system" are just *way* too broad of terms to have an explicit definitions. If anything, it's a *philosophical* question what counts as a logical system, or what counts as a formal system, and certainly there will be shades of grey in between.

But the fact of the matter is that, ultimately, people will use a variety of notations/conventions, and you'll inevitably find disparate uses of the same term coming from different authors. Your best option, I would think, is to just *pick something* and stick with it when you're first learning, and not worry about it. Afterwards, when you're more comfortable with the *notions*, you can decide for yourself what it makes sense to call them.

You may have come across this already, but Peter Smith has a nice ["Teach Yourself Logic"](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-1.pdf) guide with book recommendations. The terms that you mentioned seem mostly to involve proof-theoretic terms. The basic idea is that "axiom systems" (or "Hilbert systems") and "natural deduction systems" are two different kinds of proof systems. My opinion: if you want to learn more about proof systems, and you've already seen a bit of introductory mathematical logic, I would say Negri and von Plato is a good place to start. If you're completely new to logic, I would recommend reading some [Barwise and Etchemendy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1575866323) to get a feel for how natural deduction systems work, and then reading [Enderton](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520)'s introduction to mathematical logic.